# PHP Sibling Class Inheritance

Tags: php, extension-methods, multiple-inheritance

I'm a bit confused on whether or not this is possible.  I've checked a couple of posts here on SO and they don't really explain what I'm looking for.

I have 3 classes.   One main class and two classes extending that main class.  (see code below).   Is it possible to run a method in one of the two extended classes from it's sibling (the other extended class)?

If it's not possible, how can I change my code to accomplish what I'm doing in the example below?

**DECLARATION**

```
class A {

  public function __construct() {
     //do stuff
  }

}

class B extends A {

  private $classb = array();

  public function __construct() {
     parent::__construct();
     //do stuff
  }

  public function get($i) {
                return $this->classb[$i];
  }

  public function set($i, $v) {
    $this->classb[$i] = $v;
  }

}

class C extends A {

  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    //do stuff
  }

  public function display_stuff($i) {
    echo $this->get($i);  //doesn't work
    echo parent::get($i);  //doesn't work
  }
}
```

**USAGE**

```
$b = new B();
$c = new C();

$b->set('stuff', 'somestufftodisplay');
$c->display_stuff('stuff');   //   <----- Displays nothing.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code shows an additional problem apart from the main question so there are really two answers:

1. No, you cannot run a method from a sibling class in another sibling class. If you need that, the method should be in the parent class. The same applies to properties.
2. You cannot use the value of a property from one object in another object, even if they are both of the same class. Setting a property value in one object sets its value only there as different objects can have the same properties with completely different values. If you need to share the value of a property between the objects and also be able to modify it, you should use a [static property](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php). In this case you would have to define that in the parent class, see my previous point.

So to make it work, you would need something like

```
class A {

  private static $var = array();

  public function get($i) {
     return self::$var[$i];
  }

  public function set($i, $v) {
     self::$var[$i] = $v;
  }
}

class B extends A {

}

class C extends A {

  public function display_stuff($i) {
    echo $this->get($i); // works!
  }
}

$b = new B();
$c = new C();

$b->set('stuff', 'somestufftodisplay');
$c->display_stuff('stuff');
```

[An example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/hJE0kf).

Comment: sorry what do yo umean by my code doesn't match.  I don't understand.

Comment: display_stuff() in class C is trying to run class B's  "get" method.   How does that not match my question ?

Comment: @BestProgrammer Yes, that is my first point. But you are also trying to access a property that you have set for your `$b` object from your `$c` object. Note that even if everything was in the `A` class, it still would not work as the value of a property in the `$b` object is not available to the `$c` object, even if they have the exact same class.

Comment: @BestProgrammer Edited the introduction to make it more clear. So to make it work, you need both: move everything (property and methods) to the parent class *and* make the property static.

Comment: OK thanks, so try moving the $classb property to class A?  And make it static?   Do you see how I'm dynamically setting the values of that using an array as the property?   Will that still work with a static property?

Comment: @BestProgrammer I have added an example. Note that when you set or modify a static variable, that will apply to the class so all objects that have that class (or inherited) will have these values changed / set. So where normal properties apply to a specific object, static properties apply to the class and all objects that inherit it.

Comment: I missed the self:: part i was ripping my hair out haha.  I finally got it working though.   Does not work as protected only static, as you said as well.  Thx for the help.